# How to execute cucumber test serial and then in parallel?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Well this is my scenario:
We have an automation framework written using ruby and Capybara and for the test cases we use Cucumber, we create a feature extremely huge and took a lot of time to be executed, so we consider to use parallel execution, but that is where we have doubts about it.

We have preconditions that should be executed one after the other, then the real test cases are executed and those can be executed in parallel but not before the precondition scenarios.

```
#Below my Preconditions that have to be executed in sequence
Scenario: Precondition A
  Given I navigate to main site

Scenario: Precondition B
      Given I login to main site

Scenario: Precondition C
      Given I post a message

#Below my Test cases that can be executed in parallel
Scenario: Test 1
      Given I Test font in comment

Scenario: Test 2
      Given I test syntax in comment

Scenario: Test 3
      Given I check for images in comment
```

(Sorry for the crappy example)

I was researching for more info regarding "parallel_test" using tags and groups but I couldn't find any info related to my problem specifically.

Is there a way to execute first a sequence of test cases and then the rest in parallel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd recommend to move preconditions/setup steps into hooks using tags:

`project/features/support/hooks.rb`:

```
Before('@with_posted_message') do
  step 'I navigate to main site'
  step 'I login to main site'
  step 'I post a message'
end
```

---

Then your feature file `project/features/message.feature` would look like:

```
@with_posted_message
Feature: Message

  Scenario: Test 1
    Given I Test font in comment

  Scenario: Test 2
    Given I test syntax in comment

  Scenario: Test 3
    Given I check for images in comment
```

---

To run cucumber tests in parallel and group by scenarios you will need to use `cucumber 1.3.20` because in cucumber 2.0 functionality which allowed to group by scenarios is [broken/changed](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/blob/72b7ba1d33b2b16a2901b2450a2448329cdafef0/lib/parallel_tests/cucumber/scenario_line_logger.rb#L10). So you either need to revert [this change](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/commit/ea51ab4685eae388a09a55e7093dedaba3a4bb0b), either comment/remove raise statement locally.

`project/Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'cucumber', '1.3.20'
gem 'parallel_tests'
```

After reverting to `cucumber 1.3.20`, most likely you will need to execute next command to update dependencies:

```
bundle update
```

---

`project/features/config/cucumber.yml`:

```
default: --require features
```

---

Supposedly, you want to run your tests in parallel on `3` cores:

```
bundle exec parallel_cucumber --type cucumber -n 3 features/message.feature --group-by scenarios
```

Your output should start with this line indicating that you are running tests in parallel:

```
3 processes for 3 scenarios, ~ 1 scenarios per process
```

Comment: Kirill Zhukov, your answer is pretty good!!
We will try using hooks (which we did not thought of at first), or fail in the attempt as it is a very long feature with A LOT of preconditions before and between test cases, and see how it goes.
You will be the first one to know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear the first thing you need to do prior to taking any additional step to run parallel tests is not make tests dependent of each other... that's just a trap to over complicate your test suite and a crappy practice...

regarding running tests in parallel, have you thought of moving that responsibility to your CI tool (E.g jenkins)?... Rather than reusing a server to handle multiple test runs and then coding around it in your test suite, have Jenkins assign multiple test suites focused in a particular set of tests simultaneously seems more reliable. That's the path I would take... Do it via code just seems smelly